# Подсчитать сколько чисел из одного файла попадают в каждый интервал из заданных в другом файле

Tags: python

У меня имеются два файла:

`phones.txt`

```
0.12
0.32
0.43
0.69
0.77
0.96
1.15
```

`syllabes.txt`

```
0
0.44
0.7
1.16
```

Мне нужно посчитать количество строк в первом файле по отношению ко второму. Например:

```
0 < 0.12 < 0.44 
0 < 0.32 < 0.44
0 < 0.32 < 0.44
```

Таким образом на выходе должно получится:

```
3
1
3
```

Мой код:

```
input_syl = open("syllable.txt", "r")
input_phone = open("phones.txt", "r") 

count = 0
for line_p in input_phone:
    for line_s in input_syl:
        if line_p < line_s:
            count += 1
        print count
```

P.S. Если понадобится более толковое объяснение, спрашивайте.

Comment: @MaxU Спасибо, исправила! Должно быть 1.15 в первом файле и 1.16 во втором.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться модулем Pandas - функция [pd.cut()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) возвращает полуоткрытые интервалы:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.read_csv(r'D:\download\syllabes.txt', header=None, squeeze=True)
p = pd.read_csv(r'D:\download\phones.txt', header=None, squeeze=True)
res = p.groupby(pd.cut(p, bins=s, right=False)).count()
```

Результат:

```
In [95]: print(res)
0
[0.0, 0.44)    3
[0.44, 0.7)    1
[0.7, 1.16)    3
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

в виде списка:

```
In [96]: res.tolist()
Out[96]: [3, 1, 3]
```

как работает функция `pd.cut()`:

```
In [97]: pd.cut(p, bins=s, right=False)
Out[97]:
0    [0.0, 0.44)
1    [0.0, 0.44)
2    [0.0, 0.44)
3    [0.44, 0.7)
4    [0.7, 1.16)
5    [0.7, 1.16)
6    [0.7, 1.16)
Name: 0, dtype: category
Categories (3, interval[float64]): [[0.0, 0.44) < [0.44, 0.7) < [0.7, 1.16)]

In [98]: pd.cut(p, bins=s, right=True)
Out[98]:
0    (0.0, 0.44]
1    (0.0, 0.44]
2    (0.0, 0.44]
3    (0.44, 0.7]
4    (0.7, 1.16]
5    (0.7, 1.16]
6    (0.7, 1.16]
Name: 0, dtype: category
Categories (3, interval[float64]): [(0.0, 0.44] < (0.44, 0.7] < (0.7, 1.16]]
```

Comment: Премного благодарна! Низкий поклон!

Answer (score 3):

Для этого [подходит `numpy.historgram()` функция](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np 

a = np.loadtxt('numbers.txt')
bins = np.loadtxt('bins.txt')
print(a)
print(bins)
hist, _ = np.histogram(a, bins)
print(hist)
```

[Результат](https://repl.it/@zed1/numpy-histogram):

```
[0.12 0.32 0.43 0.69 0.77 0.96 1.15]
[0.   0.44 0.7  1.16]
[3 1 3]
```

То есть:

- **3** значения находятся в диапазоне `0 <= x < 0.44`
- **1** значение — `0.44 <= x < 0.7`
- **3** значения — `0.7 <= x <= 1.16`

Для сравнения, вот вариант на чистом Питоне (он использует факт, что числа отсортированы в обоих файлах и все числа из `numbers.txt` попадают в диапазоны заданные в `bins.txt`):

```
with open('numbers.txt') as numbers_file, \
        open('bins.txt') as bins_file:
    bins = map(float, bins_file)
    a, b = next(bins), next(bins)
    count = 0
    for f in map(float, numbers_file):
        while f >= b:  # end of the bin
            print(count)
            count = 0
            a, b = b, next(bins)
        assert a <= f < b
        count += 1
    print(count)
```

В отличии от первого варианта, самая правая граница здесь не включена в последнюю ячейку, то есть `0.7 <= x < 1.16`.

Вывод:

```
3
1
3
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! + 1 Не хватает репутации пока.